# How to complete/close Azure pull request by default when Branches are merged in Azure?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a process of creating pull request before deploying a work item. Pull request will run some quality gates and a reviewer will approve the process (granted if everything is fine). Then the actual deployment is done using a third party tool rather that merging the pull request from Azure itself. **Third party tool is merging the source to target as a normal pull request would do.**

I have two problems in this process.

1. How to auto complete/close the pull request when branches are merged
   outside of pull request? **Currently pull request status shows as
   merged when third party tool does the deployment** but PR itself
   does not get closed. This creates additional manual work to complete
   which is not ideal.
2. How to do above task without automatically
   deleting the source branch as it will be needed in the future as
   well?

I know this can be automated in other providers but couldn't find a way to do it in Azure.

Comment: Perhaps there is an API that is capable of closing the pull requests?